# How count agents from utilities collection with specific characteristic?

Tags: java, collections, anylogic

There are two types of agents in my Model:

1. AgentA - it's a parcel which must be delivered to the DeliveryPoint. This AgentA has a corresponding parameter "DeliveryPoint".
2. AgentB - it's a package (an agent-container) containing parcels (AgentA). This AgentB has a parameter "DeliveryPoint" too that depends on the "DeliveryPoint" of the parcel (AgentA) delivering at the moment.
   I need to count agents AgentA in the agent-container AgentB which meet the given condition:
   AgentA.DeliveryPoint == AgentB.DeliveryPoint

I tried this expression:

**count(agentB.contents(), p -> ((AgentA)agentB.contents()).DeliveryPoint == agentB.DeliveryPoint))**

Code example:

```
  private void _movingToDeliveryPoint_onExit_xjal( final com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Delay<AgentB> self, AgentB agent ) {
    
traceln(count(agent.contents(), p -> ((AgentA)agent.contents()).DeliveryPoint == agent.DeliveryPoint));
  }
```

but when I run my Model, I recieve this error in the block "Delay" ("movingToDeliveryPoint") that executes this code:

*java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList cannot be cast to smm_chain.AgentA*

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.base/java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList cannot be cast to smm_chain.AgentA
    at smm_chain.sc.lambda$0(sc.java:5168)
    at com.anylogic.engine.UtilitiesCollection.count(Unknown Source)
    at smm_chain.sc._movingToDeliveryPoint_onExit_xjal(sc.java:5168)
    at smm_chain.sc.access$25(sc.java:5163)
    at smm_chain.sc$17.onExit(sc.java:2319)
    at smm_chain.sc$17.onExit(sc.java:1)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Delay.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Delay.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Delay$6.onExit(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBuffer.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBuffer.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBuffer$1.onExit(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock.c(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock$1.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InPort.receiveImmediately(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.InputBlock$1.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutPort.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock$2.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.OutputBlock$2.action(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.AsynchronousExecutor_xjal.executeActionOf(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.EventTimeout.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.b(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.nb(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.k(Unknown Source)
    at com.anylogic.engine.Engine$a.run(Unknown Source)
```

Could you help me?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Read this first - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. "Help others reproduce the problem"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Sam this is a fair question for the #anylogic tag, it is good enough if you know the software :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `agentB.contents()`. Although it looks like a good method, it is not supposed to be used by modellers.

Also, do not compare objects using `==`. Use the `equals()` method instead.

Do this, assuming you have a population or list named `myAgentsA` of `AgentA` within `AgentB`:

```
 count(myAgentsA, a->a.DeliveryPoint.equals(DeliveryPoint))
```

This assumes you call the code from within `AgentB`